# How to copy checkbox form fields from 1 form to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an HTML form built with PHP that basically shows a list of records, this list of records has a FORM because it has a Checkbox filed next to each record which allows me to mass do actions on a set of records.

My issue is I recently added in a comments section under each record and that comment section allows for a quick comment post, so it has it's own FORM for each records comment section, this of course broke my checkbox form as the comment forms close `</form>`

At the bottom of the list of records is a drop down form field which list actions I can do with the Selected checkboxes records.  This is the part that no longer works as it cannot have access to the checkboxes records list anymore as that is now part of a different `<FORM>`

So my thought on a quick solution, using JavaScript, if I can somehow copy hte checkbox form fields array to my new form at the bottom of that page to do mass record updates.

My checkbox fields next to each record look like this now...

```
<input id="cb-select-1" type="checkbox" name="record_update[]" value="' . $dbresult->id . '">
```

So using JavaScript is it possible to copy the contents of `record_update[]` to another new form field in a different Form on the page?

Here is a better example in very basic form to show what I need to accomplish....

```
<form name="Form-A" id="form-a">
    <input id="cb-select-1" type="checkbox" name="record_update[]" value="355">
    <input id="cb-select-1" type="checkbox" name="record_update[]" value="455">
    <input id="cb-select-1" type="checkbox" name="record_update[]" value="555">
    ...lots more Database records with a checkbox to select the item for a mass record change
</form>


<form name="Form-B" id="form-b">
    <!-- This hidden field should have an array of all the ID's from form-a that have CHECKED checkboxes ONLY -->
    <input type="hidden" name="record_update_ids">
    <input type="submit" name="" id="doaction2" class="button" value="Update Records">
</form>
```

UPDATED code that mass selects and de-selects my checkboxes on the page now...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAll(bx) {
      var cbs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for(var i=0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        if(cbs[i].type == "checkbox") {
          cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: By javascript, do you mean jquery as well since you tagged the question with it?

Comment: it's possible, but as @Huangism said you tagged jquery, and it will be the best solution.
something like:
$('input:checkbox[name=record_update]').each(function(){ $('#anotherField').append(($(this).value()); });

Comment: jQuery is fine to use thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want is copy the checkboxes from one form to another? In that case do it:
$("input[name='record_update[]']:checked").each(function(){ $(this).clone().appendTo('#idOfOtherForm'); });
let me know

Comment: @adolfotcar I think this could almost work if I make the form field on form 2 be hidden...what I need is for the 2nd form to submit a field that contains all the ID numbers for records that are checked.  SO it would need to be a live update on From B to check and un-check items as they are checked and un-checked.  What I really need is a list of ID numbers for only the check items to post on form b when it is submitted

Comment: hummm, so you want when the user checks the checkbox it's added to the other form? try this:
$("input[name='record_update[]']").click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
   $(this).clone().appendTo('#idOfOtherForm');
 });

Comment: if instead of copying the whole field, you just wand add its id to a texarea, for example, change the part of $(this).clone().appendTo('#idOfOtherForm') to $('#idOfTextArea').val($('#idOfTextArea').val()+'\n'+$(this).attr('id))

Comment: I say ID but in reality I meant the value="355" the 355 the number part is an ID in my database, not the CSS ID, thanks I will try these out

Comment: so instead of $(this).attr('id') use $(this).val()

Comment: @adolfotcar Could you please post this as an answer and I will select as the answer as I have gotten it to work 90% from your code.  I have 2 more issues to tackle now, 1 is I have a checkbox at the top of the page that selects all checkboxes and un-selects all checkboxes, sort of like Gmail does when selecting mass amount of emails.  I need to figure a way to make this work when items are checked using that method, I have posted my code that mass-selects and un-check checkboxes to my question above too. Another issue, once an item is added if I un-check the checkbox it does not remove it

Comment: so, let's say that you checkbox to select all has id="chkAll":
$('#chkAll').click(function(){ $("input[name='record_update[]']").each(function(){ $(this).click(); }); });

Comment: @adolfotcar Genius! thanks for the help, if you want to post this as and answer i Will select it as the best answer

Comment: another suggestions, instead of a textarea you could add a hidden input for each checked box. it'll help coz you can add an id for these hidden inputs, and is easier to remove 'em. also they are inputs, so the will be post along with the form...

Comment: @adolfotcar Hello that is how it is working now, it is actually adding  the new checkbox items as new array items to a `HIDDEN` item on the 2nd form which makes them hidden, also I have added some classes and ID's and have it removing the item when un-checked, thanks for your help

Comment: My finalized JS code http://laravel.io/bin/QkXPx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you check a check box, adds an hidden input to the second form:

```
$("input[name='record_update[]']").click(function(){
    var chkId = $(this).attr('id');
    var chkVal = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            id: 'input_'+chkId,
            name: 'input_'+chkId,
            value: chkVal
        }).appendTo('#secondForm');
    else
        //if isn't checked removes it
        $('#input_'+chkId).remove(); 
});
```

when you click in the 'Check All' button, adds all to the text area:

```
$("#chkAl").click(function(){
    $("input[name='record_update[]']").click(function(){
        //skips the already checked
        if (!($(this).is(':checked')))
            $(this).click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/clone/

http://jsfiddle.net/MA3x4/1/

In document ready do the following

```
$('#form-a').find('input:checkbox[name="record_update[]"]').each(function () {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#form-b');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and example.  The issue I see right now is the checkboxes are checked after the page is loaded and instead of cloning them I need to get a list of all checked items as they are check and u-checked and then take that list of ID numbers and set them on a hidden field.  I realize I could probably use this clone and just make the field on Form 2 be hidden with CSS, so the only obstacle now would be to make it more of a live thing to add and remove checked items as they are checked and un-checked from form A

Comment: @jasondavis that's something entirely different. I would suggest to update the question to exactly what you want to achieve and remove the noise or ask a question specifically on the obstacle part you have now. Also, your ID are not unique.